# How to use an array inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a stored procedure that accepts an array argument and runs a dynamically created query using `execute immediate`. In the dynamic query, I would like to pass the array along with a set of columns in each row to a stored function.

For any other type of argument, this would be straightforward. For an integer, I would use format as follows:

`execute immediate format(""" SELECT %d*value1 as scaled_value FROM (...) """)`

But there does not seem to be a format specifier for arrays. One way to do this would be for me to write a pretty printer for arrays, which loops through an array and constructs the corresponding string `[a, b, c, ...]` but that approach seems cumbersome. Is there a supported way of doing this?

Comment: It seems unusual not to use an array along with UNNEST, but to use it in the form of an array literal. Are you able to share the select statement if you want generate by *execute immediate* ?

Comment: and for an array, **%t** in *FORMAT('%t', ['a', 'b', 'c'])*  can be used, I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: `%t` was exactly what I needed. My eyes just skipped over the description in the documentation because it starts with an example in which it is used for a timestamp, so I assumed it meant timestamp. I have a UDF written in Javascript that accepts the array. I guess I could also pass around tables with UNNEST, but the operations are complex and Javascript works better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jaytiger , for using an array inside an execute immediate statement, %t can be used inside the FORMAT function. You can  use it as `FORMAT('%t', ['a', 'b', 'c'])`.